# How to call PSP22::approve function from Frontend

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, rust, token, openbrush

Any guidance on how to call my psp22 approve function from the front end ? This is currently how I'm doing it but it doesn't seem to give increased allowance (although its successful) :

```
import { ContractPromise } from '@polkadot/api-contract';
import { web3Accounts, web3Enable, web3FromSource, isWeb3Injected } from '@polkadot/extension-dapp';
import abi from './alephcontract.json';
import abi_psp22 from './psp22.json';
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api');
const { BN } = require('@polkadot/util');

const batchApprove = async (tokens, recipients, amounts) => {
    try {

      if (recipients.length === 0 || amounts.length === 0 || tokens.length === 0) {
        throw new Error('recipients and amounts must be non-empty');
      }

      if (recipients.length !== amounts.length || recipients.length !== tokens.length) {
        throw new Error('recipients and amounts must be the same length');
      }

      const wsProvider = new WsProvider('wss://ws.test.azero.dev');
      const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider: wsProvider });


      const injector = await web3FromSource('polkadot-js');
      const allAccounts = await web3Accounts();
      api.setSigner(injector.signer);

      let txs = [];
      const AlephcontractAddress = '5cJdgjhx1234567890...';

      const formattedAmounts = amounts.map((amount, index) => {
        const formatted = new BN(amount).mul(new BN(10).pow(new BN(12)));
        console.log(formatted.toString())
        return formatted.toString();
      });


      amounts.map(async (amount, index) => {

        const Contract = new ContractPromise(api, abi_psp22, tokens[index]);

        txs.push(await Contract.tx['psp22::approve'](tokens[index], AlephcontractAddress, amount))

      })




      // construct the batch and send the transactions
      await api.tx.utility
        .batch(txs)
        .signAndSend(allAccounts[0].address, async ({ status }) => {
          if (status.isInBlock) {
            
                console.log(`included in ${status}`);
                 //perform a transfer

          }
        });

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

But the allowance remains at 0 when I check afterwards.

**PS : I am using polkadot.js package for the interactions**

Comment: Please provide whole code or the link to github. What is the difference between `tokenAddress` in ContractPromise and "token`s`Address" you are using in Contract.tx?

Comment: @Maario The question context has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by simply **specifying the `gasLimit`**.

```
const result = Contract.tx['psp22::approve']({
  gasLimit: api.createType('WeightV2', {
    refTime: 99999999999,
    proofSize: 99999999999,
  })
}
  , AlephcontractAddress, api.createType("Balance", 100));
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I approach such error is in 2 steps.

1. Make sure contract works.

Use [Contracts-UI](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/), deploy the contract and check that approve/allowance work as you expected.

2. Dry-run Tx

Before sending Tx, first send `query` for the same ink! message. That will dry-run your `approve` message and you can capture (console.log) the error if there is any

```
const result = await Contract.query['psp22::approve'](tokens[index], AlephcontractAddress, amount))
console.log(result);
```

BTW, with the `approve` it is most likely that you use wrong signing address to give the approval

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're not using `await`, you can also check how we've implemented it in the [typechain-polkadot](https://github.com/Brushfam/typechain-polkadot)

Comment: Appreciate the help! I will probably use this for production build. I tried putting await before the call but it didn't seem to work. I'm updating my question with the full context

Comment: The problem is that you are making an extrinsic without sending it, [check out this](https://github.com/Brushfam/typechain-polkadot/blob/master/packages/typechain-types/src/tx.ts)

Comment: Am I not doing that here :  await api.tx.utility
        .batch(txs)
        .signAndSend(...) ?